# Create-react-app hangs when trying to make a reactjs project or intialize it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, create-react-app

I am getting

```
Creating a new React app in D:\project 
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

And it hangs there forever

my system is - Windows 10, Node - v12.18.0, NPM - 6.14.5

Comment: what command did you run ?

Comment: npx create-react-app myapp

Comment: and in another cloned project "npm install" - it also hangs. but the strange thing is vuejs and nuxtjs are working fine with "npx create-nuxt-app "

Comment: 1. Did you ever installed cra before or is this first time ?
2. Did you try to install cra in c drive ?

Comment: I am using react for the last 2 yrs now. And always use it with CRA. after updating to the recent windows update I started facing this problem :(

Comment: Is it wrking in C: drive ?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Without seeing more details its like shooting in the dark to try and solve this, could you try running "npx create-react-app my-app --verbose"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options you can try.:

1. Try this command in both `C` and `D` drive:
   `create-react-app myapp --use-npm --cache /tmp/empty-cache`
2. Else try, `npm install npm@latest -g`
3. Else try, Uninstall and re-install Node again.